# Antonym for "procrastinator"

Tags: single-word-requests

Disclaimer: I'm not looking for an antonym of "[procrastination](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59759/what-is-the-opposite-of-procrastination-in-one-word)" or "[procrastinate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375579/opposite-of-procrastinate)" (Noun for an action and a verb, respectively).

I am looking for an antonym to "procrastinator" (noun for a person) that could be used to fill in the blank in the following sentence:

"I am not a procrastinator, so I am a _______________."

Comment: Try antonyms of [procrastinate](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/procrastinate): complete, expedite, advance, finish, hasten, push, accelerate.  You can add the "-er"/"-or" suffix yourself.

Comment: This is related to ["What's the opposite of 'last-minute (Christmas) shopping'?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/468244/whats-the-opposite-of-last-minute-christmas-shopping)

Comment: I get shit done. If there is no noun to crowbar in my sentence, I rewrite the sentence. That's because I get shit done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, a synonym of "PROCRASTINATOR" is "THINKER".

Then the antonym will be ***DOER***:

​
= someone who gets actively involved in something, rather than just thinking or talking about it:

// There are too many thinkers and not enough doers in this office.

(https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doer)

Answer (score 3):

I am a proactive person.

I am a go-getter.

These both come to mind. Go-getter may be more similar to what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

> hustler

Seems like a good candidate

Answer (score 1):

Self-starter is another option.